# List of Group Policy Objects via PowerShell

Tags: group-policy, powershell

Does anyone know how to get a list of GPO (Group Policy Objects) from a Windows 2003 domain via PowerShell or some other way if PowerShell can’t do this?

I know that Server 2008 has some cmdlets for Group Polices but how can it be done for a Windows 2003 domain?

Looked on Google but no luck.

Thanks

Gary

Answer (score 1):

try SDM software's group policy cmdlets [SDM GPMC PowerShell Cmdlets 1.3](http://www.sdmsoftware.com/freeware)

Comment: Good idea, but trying to make the script PowerShell only so we don't need to install different cmdlets on all the customers.  But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GPMC API to get a list of all GPOs:

```
$gpm = New-Object -ComObject GPMgmt.GPM
$constants = $gpm.GetConstants()
$domain = $env:USERDOMAIN
$gpmDomain =$gpm.GetDomain($domain ,"", $constants.UseAnyDC)
$gpmSearch = $gpm.CreateSearchCriteria()
$gpmDomain.SearchGPOs($gpmSearch)
```

Comment: Thanks Shay,  I did try that using some examples last week.  But I get:-

Comment: $Constants=$gpm.Getconstants()
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'Getconstants'.
At line:1 char:29
+ $Constants=$gpm.Getconstants <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Getconstants:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with this, used the GPOINFO tool.  Not pretty but got what we needed:-

```
Write-Host "Counting GPO's"
$dom=[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetComputerDomain()
$PDC=$dom.PdcRoleOwner
gpotool.exe /dc:$PDC > GPOToolRep.txt
$GCReport=Get-Content -Path GPOToolRep.txt
$TextOut+="$($GCReport[4])`n
```

Thanks for all the responses....Gary